# Java game with libGDX: my ship cant move to the right

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm doing a Java Project that consists of making a "Space Invaders" clone. I'm starting with the ship movement, searching on stackOverflow I found this code:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) )
    x -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * PlayerSpeed;
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) )
    x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * PlayerSpeed;
```

I use it to the playerShip(the class below):

```
public class PlayerShip extends Ship {
    private Animator animator;
    private float PlayerSpeed = 20.0f;
    private int x,y;

    public PlayerShip(SpriteBatch batch){
        this.animator=new Animator(batch,"ship.png", 5, 2);
    }

    public void create(){
        animator.create();
    }

    public void render(){
        this.animator.render(this.x,this.y);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) )
            x -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * PlayerSpeed;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) )
            x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * PlayerSpeed;
    }



    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Game(main):

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private BackgroundManagement backgroundManagement;
    private BitmapFont font;

    private PlayerShip player;
    private SmallShip smallShip;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(600, 800);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        player = new PlayerShip(batch);
        smallShip = new SmallShip(batch);
        player.create();
        player.setX(300);
        player.setY(100);
        smallShip.create();
        smallShip.setX(200);
        smallShip.setY(400);
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("gamefont.fnt"),
                Gdx.files.internal("gamefont.png"), false);
        backgroundManagement = new BackgroundManagement(batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        backgroundManagement.render();
        player.render();
        smallShip.render();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

When trying on my code, the ship didn't move to the right, I had tried various solutions but i didn't found any, Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, according to the [documentation](https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/a-simple-game) anyway. You can move to the left and not to the right?

Answer (score 1):

The position of the ship is an integer. Your increment is a float. You maybe have a decent graphics card which can render a simple game at e.g. 200+ fps continuous render (or more even could be crazy). In 200fps case the increment would be (1/200)*20 = 1/10 float.

`integer += .1f`
won't change the original integer.

Change your position to a float as well, then cast (or convert) to an integer when you need to actually render so x can increment very small values.